# Apply shell script to strings inside a file and replace string inside quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Suppose I have a file `greeting.txt`(double quotes are inside the file, only one line):

```
"Hello world!"
```

And a file `names.txt`(no double quotes, many lines, show 2 here as an example):

```
Tom
Mary
```

Then I want to create a bash script that create files `greeting_to_Tom.txt`:

```
"Hello Tom!"
```

and `greeting_to_Mary.txt`:

```
"Hello Mary!"
```

I'm quite newbie in shell script, so after I piece together what I searched, I tried:

`greetingToAll.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="greeting_to_"$1".txt"
cp greeting.txt $filename
sed -i 's/world/$1/' $filename
```

and at command line I type:

```
cat names.txt | xargs ./greetingToAll.sh
```

But only `Tom` is recognized and it's wrongly replaced by `$1`. Anybody can help me with this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create `greetingToAll` as the below:

```
greeting=$(cat greeting.txt)
while read -r name; do 
  echo "$greeting" | sed "s/world/$name/" > "greeting_to_$name.txt"
done < "$1"
```

You can call as:

```
./greetingToAll names.txt
```

Depending on what you're doing, it might be an even better idea to parameterise the script to take the greeting from any file you choose:

```
greeting=$(cat "$1")
while read -r name; do 
  echo "$greeting" | sed "s/world/$name/" > "greeting_to_$name.txt"
done < "$2"
```

Then can call as:

```
./greetingToAll greeting.txt names.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `xargs` command. It takes the content of `names.txt` and puts it as arguments to the `./greetingToAll.sh` command. So the resulting call is

```
./greetingToAll.sh Tom Mary
```

In this call, $1 is Tom and that's get replaced correctly. You might want to do

```
cat names.txt | while read name; do ./greetingToAll.sh "$name"; done
```

This calls `./greetingToAll.sh` twice, once as `./greetingToAll.sh "Tom"` and once as `./greetingToAll.sh "Mary"`.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` one-liner can also do the job:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[++n]=$1; next} $2=="world!\"" {
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++){s=$0; sub(/world/, a[i], s);
      print s > "greeting_to_" a[i] ".txt"}}' names.txt greetings.txt
```

**Verify:**

```
grep -H Hello greeting_to_*
greeting_to_Mary.txt:"Hello Mary!"
greeting_to_Tom.txt:"Hello Tom!"
```